# Longest prefix of string S that is also a sub-prefix of S in linear time

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings, string-matching

As the question suggest. I want an algorithm that runs in linear time which finds the longest prefix of a substring that is a sub-prefix of the same string.

**Formally:**

---

Given a string $S$ of length $n$, we define a function $\delta_{S}:$ $[n]\rightarrow[n]$ as follows. For each integer $w$, $1\le w\le n$, $\delta$ is defined:

$\delta_{S}[w] = \max\{i\colon S[1...i] = S[w...w+i-1]\}$.

The algorithm should find $\delta_{S}[w]$ for each $1\le w \le n$.

---

Question should be solved using the $\pi$ function of KMP's preprocessing.

---

The question can be easily solved in $O(n^2)$. The $O(n^2)$ solution is simple and straightforward. For each $w$, manually find the longest prefix. Each iteration could take $O(n)$ time, thus for all $1 \le w \le n$ it would take $O(n^2)$. However, the question should be solved in a linear time. This question falls down under string matching, in particular, KMP. I know the question should be solved using the function $\pi$ from KMP's pre-processing. However, I can't solve the question.

---

**What I tried:**

Assume in this answer that all arrays starts from index 1 and ends at index n. Not from 0 until n-1.

Create a new array $\delta$. Initialize $\delta[1]$ = n, since this is always true, and initialize the rest of the array to be 0.

Create an array $\pi$ and compute $\pi(w)$ for $1\le w \le n$, and then for each index, subtract the index of the cell of the array from the content of the array. For instance, $i-\pi(i)$ and then check if this value is greater from $\delta[i]$. However, I seem to get stuck and can't solve the problem. I've tried to solve the problem for a couple of days before posting here, I can't seem to really fully understand the question and how to approach it.

Comment: If you construct a suffix tree/suffix array, does this become easy to solve?

Comment: Actually yes, it makes easier to solve and I haven't noticed that it becomes much easier to solve it by a suffix tree. However, I'm required to solve this question using the pi function from KMP preprocessing. Additionally, I'd really like to understand how can I really solve it using KMP's preprocessing function.

Comment: You were asked to compute something called the z-function (https://cp-algorithms.com/string/z-function.html).

Comment: Isn't this the function computed by KMP itself? can you explain how this is different?

Comment: No, it's not the same. KMP pi(i) function computes the longest prefix that is also a suffix of the substring S[0....i]. As stated in the question, given phi(w), we need to find the longest prefix of S that is also a prefix of the substring that starts at S[w].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you mentioned is correct. Note as the comments pointed out, that you want to compute the so called $z$-function:
$$
z[i] := \max_{k\in[n]}\{k\,|\, S[1:k] = S[i:i+k],\,\, 0\leq i+k \leq n\}
$$
using the $\pi$ function:
$$
\pi[i] := \max_{k\in[n]}\{k\,|\, S[1:k] = S[i-k:i],\,\, 0\leq i-k \leq n\}
$$
We claim that
$$
z[i] := \max_{k\in[n]}\{k\,|\, \pi[i+k] = k,\,\, 0\leq i+k\leq n\}
$$
Notice for each $i\in [n]$:
$$
\pi[i+k] = k \iff S[1:k] = S[i:i+k]
$$
By taking the maximum over $k\in [n]$ our proof is complete.
This yields the algorithm:

```
z[1,...,n] = 0
for i in [n]:
    k = pi(i)
    z[i-k] = max(z[i-k],k)
```

as you already described.